# Single step debugging without spammy system files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

I am coding C++ in VS2010. I know that I can single-step debug via pressing F11 at a break point. The problem with this is that it also steps through system files that I don't need to check, some of which appear to be coded in assembly so they have a lot of lines. This makes F11 useless for this program because I can't get more than a few lines without ending up in a long system file. Worse, it sometimes pops up a message that the system code is inaccessible so I can't go further.

So my question is: Is there a way to single-step through only your own code?

Comment: Use F10 instead of F11.

Comment: [How to not step into specific functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx).